# NSURLConnection doesn't receive data when creating many downloading objects in iOS5

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios5, nsurlconnection

I have been searching for this problem on the SOF for several days and I still have not found the solution (say the same problem) yet.

I'm making and app that downloads 5 images simultaneously in an URL list (each image is on a different server).

I have an `ImageDownloader` class subclasses `NSOperation` and implements the `NSURLConnectionDataDelegate`.

So that I can add an instance of `ImageDownloader` to an `operationQueue` in the `ViewController` and it will run in a separate thread under the `operationQueue`. The line that add the downloader to the `operationQueue` is here:

```
downloader = [[ImageDownloader alloc] init];
[downloader downloadImageWithURL:[controller.URList objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",downloadIndex]] queue:queue andTag:downloadIndex + 100]; //my custom initialize
downloader.delegate = self;
[queue addOperation:downloader]; //use the addOperation method
```

Everything works fine in **iOS6** but messed up in **iOS5** (5.0 on my test device and 5.1 on my SDK), it just doesn't receive any response nor data by performing the methods `didReceiveResponse` and `didReceiveData` at all (these 2 methods are not jumped in).

After the timeout was exceeded, the runloop jumps into `didFailWithError` method and the program stalls.

As I understand, this means the runloop still runs right?

I tried to print out the `error` and all I got is: `The request timed out`.

When I reduce the number of downloading instances to 2 then it runs, but not with >=3 downloading instances.

One more information is that my network connection does limit the number of connection. But it work fine in iOS6, why it just doesn't work on iOS5?

I can still load the web in the simulator while the app is downloading.

So what kind of problem is this and how can I get over this problem?

Thanks in advance.

****Update:**** as there are many classes and the problem's not been clearly detected yet, I will share here the whole project. You can download it directly from here:
[DownloadingImage](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/15628608/Public%20files/DownloadImageByOperation.zip)

Comment: There is a limit in opening parallel connections. Check http://blog.mugunthkumar.com/articles/mobile-apps-and-number-of-concurrent-connections/

Comment: I suggest using AFNetworking https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking instead of native NSURLConnection, which could be tedious.

Comment: I've just updated my question.@KishoreK: The images are on different server. I think 5 concurrent connections with 5 different servers is nothing dangerous.@Lynayo: I want to make it on my own to deeply understand the problem so I don't want to use any library in my app. :(

Comment: Could you share some more of your code somewhere?

Comment: You haven't shared your code with us, but the `setDelegateQueue` method of `NSURLConnection` does not work properly in iOS 5 when you invoke that method from a background queue (doesn't make sense, but that's my experience; I suspect it was an iOS5 bug). Works like a champ in iOS 6, but not 5. Are you using the `setDelegateQueue` method? If that's not it, share some code with us so we can take a look at it.

Comment: Tell us how you're configuring your `NSURLConnection`.

Comment: http://eng.pulse.me/concurrent-downloads-using-nsoperationqueues/ refer this

Comment: I've just add the whole project source code to the question. Thank you guys.

Comment: I downloaded and ran it on the 5.1 simulator and it worked. Perhaps the solution is to set your target OS to 5.1 and call it a day?

Comment: By the way, I don't think this is the root cause of your problem, but you are not using `NSOperation` correctly. Everything that is in your `-downloadImageWithURL:queue:andTag:` method should really be in your `-main` method.

Comment: @Josh Hinman: I changed my target to 5.1 and it's work by **luck** (sometimes works, sometimes not,sometimes downloaded some images, then error again). Currently the `currentDownloadProcesses` in the main of `ImageDownloadController.m` is set to <3; if it is <5 then there is not a time the app works.
About the way I use the NSOperation, I made these lines of code run on main thread by purpose, because if not, it doesn't works at all. I think it's just the initialization and add operation to the queue, after that, the operationQueue dequeue those operations to separate threads. Right?

Comment: Just a quick answer, dont't know if it's the case, but I used to have the same mechanism on iOS 5, i.e. a queue holding synchronous download operations, with a limited concurrent number. This was causing lot of problems when queue was filled with many requests waiting for its turn, this led to time out and other quite unpredictable network errors, all of this with a good degree of 'randomness'. I soon get rid of it and launches the asynchronous downloading directly, with the help of a custom download controller in use by the UIViewController.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just figured out where my problem is, but not really understand why.

In my `ImageDownloader` class, I set up a runloop with `done` and `currentRunLoop` variables.
In the main method, I have a while loop for forcing the `currentRunLoop` run.

As I remove those "runLoop" stuffs, the app runs smoothly on both iOS6 and iOS5.

So change the entire `ImageDownloader.m` with these lines then it works (I commented out some useless (say harmful) lines):

```
//
//  ImageLoader.m
//  DownloadImagesTableView
//
//  Created by Viet Ta Quoc on 6/25/13.
//  Copyright (c) 2013 Viet Ta Quoc. All rights reserved.
//

#import "ImageDownloader.h"

@implementation ImageDownloader
@synthesize downloadData,delegate,queue,done,customTag;
NSRunLoop *currentRunLoop;

-(void)downloadImageWithURL:(NSString *)imageUrl queue:(NSOperationQueue*)opQueue andTag:(int)tag{
    self.customTag= tag;
    self.queue = opQueue;
//    self.done = NO;
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageUrl] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData timeoutInterval:30];
    NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self startImmediately:NO];
    [connection start];
//    currentRunLoop = [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop];
    NSLog(@"Start downloading image %d...",customTag);
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response{
    NSLog(@"Received response...");
    downloadData=[[NSMutableData alloc] initWithLength:0];
    expectedDataLength=[response expectedContentLength];
    NSLog(@"Image %d size: %lld kb",customTag,[response expectedContentLength]/1024);
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data{
    float receivedLenght = [data length];
    receivedDataLength=(receivedDataLength+receivedLenght);
    float progress=(float)receivedDataLength/(float)expectedDataLength;
    [delegate updateProgess:progress andIndex:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:customTag-100 inSection:0]];
    [self.downloadData appendData:data];
//    NSLog(@"Percentage of data received of tag %d: %f %%",self.customTag,progress*100);
}

-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection{
    [delegate finishedDownloadingImage:downloadData andTag:customTag];
//    done = YES;
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error{
    UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Warning" message:@"Network Connection Failed?" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
//    NSLog(@"%@",[error debugDescription]);
    NSLog(@"Connection failed! Error - %@ %@",[error localizedDescription],[[error userInfo] objectForKey:NSURLErrorFailingURLStringErrorKey]);
    [alert show];
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge{
    NSLog(@"Got here *(*&(**&(*&(*&(*&(*&(*&(*&(*&(*&(*&(*&(*&(*&(*&(*&(*&(*&");
}

-(void)main{
//    do{
////        NSLog(@"Running....1");
//        [currentRunLoop runUntilDate:[NSDate distantFuture]];
//        //        [currentRunLoop run];
//    } while (!done);
//    [currentRunLoop runUntilDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0.01]];
}
@end
```

Thank you guys for your supports.

**==================================================================================**

**P/s: for anyone who interested in this problem, I update here my entire solution: [DownloadImage_Final](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/15628608/Public%20files/DownloadImageByOperation_new.zip)**

Comment: I just took a look at your project. There are a couple of things: 1. you are not correctly inheriting from NSOperation. 2. You are not using an NSOperation correctly. 3. You better encapsulate the run loop into the NSOperation subclass (use either the main thread or a dedicated thread with a run loop). 4. A few design issues.  So basically, the code won't work. I would suggest, read the docs about  NSOperation and how to subclass correctly. As a jump start look at `QHTTPOperation` in Apple's samples (MVCNetworking).

Comment: Another jump start: on Gist there is a simplistic sample which defines a class `SimpleGetHTTPRequest` encapsulating a `NSURLConnection` and related state info. It can be easily modified to be subclassed from `NSOperation`. It has been specifically designed to give users an idea how to create your own "HTTPRequestOperation" class and has been steadily improved. Have fun ;) [SimpleGetHTTPRequest](https://gist.github.com/couchdeveloper/5764723)

Comment: Another issue in your code: in `addDownloadProcess:` you dispatch onto _dispatchQueue_ (which is presumable not the main queue) where the block invokes `downloadImageWithURL:`. The latter method then schedules the delegates on the current thread's run loop. However, the current thread of the dispatch queue is _unspecified_ and likely has no run loop. That has the effect, that your delegates will not be called. In order to fix this, use a dedicated thread with a run loop or use the main thread _explicitly_. Preferable implement this into your "HTTPRequest" class.

Comment: @CouchDeveloper Thank you very much! I appreciate your comments a lot. I will read it carefully!

Answer (score 0):

As I just found out, if you're using credentials there is a chance that the server will reject them randomly every once in a while.  So if you have a check to make sure previousFailureCount == 0 then you will most likely have a bug.

Comment: Thank you for your response but I haven't got your idea yet. Please explain it more please!

Comment: I was doing the following.  It appears you aren't, so... you probably don't have this issue.

    - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection
didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge {
        if(_credential && challenge.previousFailureCount == 0) {
            [[challenge sender] useCredential:_credential forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
        }
    }

Comment: Yeah, I don't have that problem. Thanks anyway.