# defunct NSURLConnection never executes or times out

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlconnection, nsurlrequest

I'm running a LOT of asynchronous (delegate, not block) `NSURLConnections` simultaneously, and they all come back very quickly as I'm hitting a LAN server.

Every so often, one `NSURLConnection` will go defunct and never return.

`connection:willSendRequest:` is called but `connection:didReceiveResponse:` (and failure) is not.

Any ideas?  I'm wondering if I should make a simple drop-in replacement using `CFNetwork` instead.

Edit: There's really not much code to show.  What I've done is created a wrapper class to download files.  I will note that the problem happens *less* when I run the connection on a separate queue - but still happens.

The general gist of what I'm doing is creating a download request for each cell as a tableview scrolls (in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`) and then asynchronously loading in an image file to the table cell if the cell is still visible.

```
_request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:_URL];
_request.cachePolicy = NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData;
_request.timeoutInterval = _timeoutInterval;

if(_lastModifiedDate) {
    [_request setValue:[_lastModifiedDate RFC1123String] forHTTPHeaderField:@"If-Modified-Since"];
}


_connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:_request
                                              delegate:self
                                      startImmediately:NO];
[_connection start];
```

As requested, instance variables:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *_request;
NSURLConnection *_connection;
```

And delegate methods:

```
- (NSURLRequest *)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection willSendRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request redirectResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
    NSLog(@"%@ send", _URL);
    return request;
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
    NSLog(@"%@ response", _URL);
    _response = (id)response;
    // create output stream
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    _receivedLength += data.length;
    _estimatedProgress = (Float32)_receivedLength / (Float32)_response.expectedContentLength;
    [_outputStream write:data.bytes maxLength:data.length];

    // notify delegate
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    // close output stream
    // notify delegate
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"%@ failure", _URL);
    // notify delegate
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection
didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge {
    if(_credential && challenge.previousFailureCount == 0) {
        [[challenge sender] useCredential:_credential forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide more detail of you code please?
Btw, I'm having a similar problem with NSURLConnection too. Do you find any common between yours and mine [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17848290/nsurlconnection-doesnt-receive-data-when-creating-many-downloading-objects-in-i)

Comment: Please show declaration for `_request` and `_connection`, and your delegate methods (stripped down). What's `delegate` by the way? Is it the view controller, another object?

Comment: It's essentially 'self' for this discussion.  I have an option on my wrapper object to use a weak proxy so that NSURLConnection doesn't keep my object alive.  That flag is off in this instance.

Comment: Are you tying the lifetime of the connections to the cells somehow?

Comment: Your usage of the output stream is wrong. You may loose data. It only works as expected for _file streams_ and _memory streams_ due to implementation details.

Comment: Your implementation of `connection:didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:` isn't correct, too. Basically, you need to check the authentication method, and then branch and take appropriate actions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After poking around in profiler, I found a lead, and it gave me a hunch.

My credentials were failing (not sure why...) and so previousFailureCount was not 0, and hence I wasn't using my credential object.

Changed the code to this and I have no problems:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge {
    if(_credential) {
        [[challenge sender] useCredential:_credential forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
    }
}
```

Comment: This isn't correct, too   ;)  You first need to check which kind of authentication is required: retrieve the protection space, then from it retrieve the authentication method. You provide the credentials only for `NSURLAuthenticationMethodHTTPBasic` and `NSURLAuthenticationMethodHTTPDigest`.

Answer (score 0):

A `NSURLConnection` will send either `didReceiveResponse` or `didFailWithError`.

Often, you're dealing with timeouts before `didFailWithError` occurs.

Comment: That is what the documentation says, but that is not happening.

Comment: @xtravar, show some code. I've used NSURLConnection extensively, and I've never had an issue that wasn't user error. :)

Comment: I've added some more details about what I'm doing.  Honestly, I've worked quite a bit with NSURLConnection too and never ran into this.  But I've never created quite so many at the same time in this fashion.